# Struggling to parse array notation

Tags: antlr4

I have a very simple grammar to parse statements.

Here are examples of the type of statements that need be parsed:

```
a.b.c 

a.b.c == "88"
```

The issue I am having is that array notation is not matching. For example, things that are not working:

```
a.b[0].c

a[3][4]
```

I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong here. (I am testing in ANTLRWorks)

Here is the grammar (`generationUnit` is my entry point):

```
grammar RatBinding;

generationUnit: testStatement | statement;

arrayAccesor : identifier arrayNotation+;
arrayNotation:  '[' Number ']';

testStatement: 
    (statement | string | Number | Bool ) 

    (greaterThanAndEqual 
        | lessThanOrEqual  
        | greaterThan
        | lessThan | notEquals | equals)

    (statement | string | Number | Bool ) 
;

part: identifier | arrayAccesor; 

statement:  part  ('.' part )*;

string: ('"' identifier '"') | ('\'' identifier '\'');

greaterThanAndEqual: '>=';
lessThanOrEqual: '<=';
greaterThan: '>';
lessThan: '<';
notEquals : '!=';
equals: '==';
identifier:   Letter (Letter|Digit)*;


Bool : 'true' | 'false';

ArrayLeft: '\u005B';
ArrayRight: '\u005D';

Letter
    :  '\u0024' |
       '\u0041'..'\u005a' |
       '\u005f '|
       '\u0061'..'\u007a' |
       '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' |
       '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' |
       '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' |
       '\u0100'..'\u1fff' |
       '\u3040'..'\u318f' |
       '\u3300'..'\u337f' |
       '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' |
       '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' |
       '\uf900'..'\ufaff'
      ;

Digit
    :  '\u0030'..'\u0039' |
       '\u0660'..'\u0669' |
       '\u06f0'..'\u06f9' |
       '\u0966'..'\u096f' |
       '\u09e6'..'\u09ef' |
       '\u0a66'..'\u0a6f' |
       '\u0ae6'..'\u0aef' |
       '\u0b66'..'\u0b6f' |
       '\u0be7'..'\u0bef' |
       '\u0c66'..'\u0c6f' |
       '\u0ce6'..'\u0cef' |
       '\u0d66'..'\u0d6f' |
       '\u0e50'..'\u0e59' |
       '\u0ed0'..'\u0ed9' |
       '\u1040'..'\u1049'
   ;

WS  :   [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You referenced the non-existent rule `Number` in the `arrayNotation` parser rule.

A `Digit` rule does exist in the lexer, but it will only match a single-digit number. For example, `1` is a `Digit`, but `10` is two separate `Digit` tokens so `a[10]` won't match the `arrayAccesor` rule. You probably want to resolve this in two parts:

1. Create a `Number` token consisting of one or more digits.

   ```
   Number
     : Digit+
     ;
   ```
2. Mark `Digit` as a fragment rule to indicate that it doesn't form tokens on its own, but is merely intended to be referenced from other lexer rules.

   ```
   fragment // prevents a Digit token from being created on its own
   Digit
     : ...
   ```

You will not need to change `arrayNotation` because it already references the `Number` rule you created here.

Comment: thanks, i discovered this stupidity a minute after posting (ashamed)

Comment: @lennel I noticed that, but still added this answer so future users could see a more complete response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Bah, waste of space. I Used Number instead of Digit in my array declaration.